# sending customized salt event with cmd.run and onfail

Tags: salt-stack

I want to trigger custom named event if sls state fails.
I have following code:

```
check-if-needs-restarting:
  {% if grains['os'] == 'CentOS' %}
  cmd.run:
  - name: needs-restarting -r
  - onfail:
    - cmd.run:
      - name: salt-call event.send needs-restarting
  {% endif %}
```

but somehow it crashes salt renderer:

```
 An un-handled exception was caught by salt's global exception handler:
SaltRenderError: Could not locate requisite of [cmd] present in state with name
```

Any idea why? I tried fire_event instead but thn I dont have custom name I want `"needs-restarting"`

Answer (score 0):

`onfail` like other global state arguments works only with states as arguments

See examples in [the official documentation](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#onfail)